# Не работает запрос в БД. Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Постараюсь поменьше воды.
Выполняю вот такой запрос:
$connection = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getConnection();
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE ID = $id")->fetch();

В ответ пустота. Если вместо $id написать число, т.е. в запросе ID = 12345, то результат есть. Пробовал преобразовать в число, хотя int изначально приходит, но не работает.

Comment: Скажу сразу, что стучусь не в <table_name>. Это я скрыл название таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В выражении

`$connection->query("SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE ID = $id")`

внутри скобок находится в кавычках SQL запрос. Это - просто строка. В этой строке не может быть Php - переменной $id. Потому что так, как это написано - нет процесса формальной подстановки значения переменной вметсо её имени.

Когда Вы "руками" делаете эту формальную подстановку - вставляя конкретное значение $id в запрос - то всё начинает работать, потому что SQL запрос, передаваемы в базу, становится осмысленным.

Более тог, я подозреваю, что при выполнении исходногокода Вам должен возвращаться не просто пустой курсор, а ошибка синтаксиса в SQL.

Как решить проблему:

коротко и неправильно:

```
    $connection->query("SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE ID = ".$id);
```

Почему это неправильно? взможность SQL injection, если в $id будет написно что то вроде

```
    $id = '1; DROP DATABASE sales;';
```

Чуть чуть лучше сделать так:

```
    $connection->query("SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE ID = ".intval($id));
```

Правильно - сделать подставновку SQL параметров средствами, которые для этого существуют в php. Сейчас постараюсь найти пример...

Comment: Пробовал так. Не работает. Есть подозрение, что что-то недоподключил, т.к. запрос выполняется в файле, который дёргается BX,ajax, хотя, если указать число как я писал запрос выполняется.

Comment: Кстати, ошибка не возвращается. Возвращается пустота. Это очень странно. Возвращалась бы ошибся - я бы знал хотя бы где рыть.

Comment: а тип поля id в самом sql - это int? А то бывают id которые не - числовые, а строковые. Тогда на SQL это выглядело бы как "select * from table1 where id='123abc';"

Comment: Тип поляd в таблице INT.

Comment: хм, есть в этом какая то интрига. скоро попробую на живом битриксе и отпишусь

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Видимо, когда сидишь часов 10-12 по уши в коде нужно вовремя себя остановить. Вместо ID инстанса подал ID пользователя. Ясен пень он ничего не вернёт, т.к. записи такой не существует. Жесть.